# Prove that if $\mathrm{rank}(A-I_n)=p$ and $\mathrm{rank}(B-I_n)=q$, then $\mathrm{rank}(AB-I_n)\leq p+q$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $A,B\in M_n\mathbb{(R)}$ be matrices with $\mathrm{rank}(A-I_n)=p$ and $\mathrm{rank}(B-I_n)=q$. Show that $\mathrm{rank}(AB-I_n)\leq p+q$.

I have no idea how to relate the two rank given to solve the question stated.

Comment: Are A and B symmetric matrices? If yes, then $rank(A-I_n)=p$ implies that $rank(A)=n-p$.
Similarly for B. 
If you know the rank of A and B, you should be able to say something about the rank of the product $AB$ and in turn the rank of $AB-I_{n}$.

Comment: The question did not state that whether the matrices are symmetric.

Comment: @ndruiven This is the exact statement of the problem. Actually this is one of past year question for the course Linear Algebra in my university.

Comment: Maybe this works...
$Rk(AB-I) = Rk(AB - A + A -I) =Rk(A(B-I) + A -I) \le min\{Rk(A),Rk(B-I)\} + Rk(A-I) \le q + p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}$
$$
\rank(AB - I) =\\ 
\rank(AB - A + A - I)=\\
\rank(A(B-I) + A-I) \leq\\
\min\{\rank(A),\rank(B-I)\} + \rank(A-I) \leq \\
\rank(B-I) + \rank(A-I) =\\
p+q
$$

Comment: a small question here: How you know that $min\{rank(A),rank(B-I)\}\leq rank(B-I)$?

Comment: In general, $\min\{a,b\} \leq b$